# Loop the timer until newAttempt == 0

Tags: java, loops, timer

When the timer goes zero, newAttempt will subtract by 1. The timer will loop back until newAttempt became zero. It'll  display an information_message saying game over. I don't know how to loop this. Whenever i run the program, my computer freezes.

Here's my program:

```
     int delay = 1000;
    int period = 1000;
    timer = new Timer();
    interval = Integer.parseInt("10");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            do{
            if (interval == 1)
                if (interval == 1)
                    timer.cancel();
            --interval;
            String interv = Integer.toString(interval);
            timerTextField.setText("0:"+interv);
            if(interval==0){
                --counter;
                newAttempt = Integer.parseInt(attemptTextField.getText());
                newAttempt -= 1;
                String convert = Integer.toString(newAttempt);
                attemptTextField.setText(convert);
                if(counter==0)
                    interval = Integer.parseInt("10");
            }
            }while(newAttempt!=0);
        }
    }, delay, period);
```

I updated my code. It's still wrong but i think i'm close.

Comment: oops sorry. ill change the code

Comment: But @hotzst is right: it shouldn't be done in a loop anyway.

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. There shouldn't be a long loop in a timer task. What are you doing with the `interval` and why are there two identical `if` conditions on it? What does `newAttempt` represent? Why does it come from a text field?

Answer (score 0):

Do not run it in a while loop. Create a `Timer` and a `TimerTask` and store the task in variable.

Then you can post the task to the timer. When the time is up the task will be executed. There you can figure out if your counter has reached 0 and if not, add another task to the timer.

Comment: like this? `--counter; ` then, `if(counter==0)`

Comment: You have this basically already in you code: counter is `newAttempt`. From the code above I gather that the number of attempts can change from one execution of the task to the next, or is `attemptTextField` a read only field?

Comment: attemptTextField is a read only field but you can change the number of attempts in the settings in main menu.

Comment: If the time's up, the newAttempt is subtracted by 1 until there's no newAttempt